# Pass custom parameters to .iss script

Tags: jenkins, inno-setup

I am trying to automatize building my application installer. I build an installer using Inno Setup Compiler. Now what I'am trying to do is to execute batch command in Jenkins that produces my program installer every time my application is built using Jenkins. Every Jenkins build changes my application workspace and i want a way to pass this workspace to the .iss script so that installer can be built with current application version.

Here is a command i use in jenkins:

```
ISCC.exe "/O%WORKSPACE%" "/Dworkspace=workspace %WORKSPACE%" script1.iss
```

And a part in iss file i want to affect:

```
[Files]
Source: "{workspace}\myapp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

But i get:

```
Error in script1.iss: Source file "{workspace}\myapp.exe" does not exist.
```

Comment: There was almost identical question asked an hour after yours: [Using path/value specified on Inno Setup compiler command-line in Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54368198/850848).