# Using path/value specified on Inno Setup compiler command-line in Inno Setup script

Tags: inno-setup

I want to pass a path (via command line arg `/D` to the script compiler) to my executable to let my script determine the application version number using `GetFileVersion`, but my syntax isn't correct. How do I pass an argument to `GetFileVersion`?
The error is: Illegal character in input file: '#' (0x23)

```
#define srcpath SOURCEPATH
#define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion(#srcpath)//error here!!!!!!

[Setup]
AppVersion={#ApplicationVersion}

[Files]
Source: "MyDllTesting.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "{srcpath}MyApplication1.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\MyApplication1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `SOURCEPATH` is a [Inno Setup preprocessor predefined variable](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars), so you need to use another name for your command-line "variable". I'll be using `SOURCE_PATH`.

---

Second, the correct syntax is:

```
#define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion(SOURCE_PATH)
```

(i.e. no hash)

Why no hash, is covered in my answer to
[Why preprocessor behaves differently in #include directive then in [Files] section Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53779355/850848)

Though the reason is basically the same, why you use no hash before `SOURCEPATH` here:

```
#define srcpath SOURCEPATH
```

On the contrary you are missing the hash in the `[Files]` section entry. The correct syntax is:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#srcpath}MyApplication1.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\MyApplication1"
```

---

And there's no need to define `srcpath` variable. `SOURCE_PATH` is variable too. So you can use it directly in any expression:

```
#define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion(SOURCE_PATH)

[Files]
Source: "{#SOURCE_PATH}MyApplication1.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\MyApplication1"
```

Comment: If I use this: #define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion(SOURCE_PATH). I get the following compile error: undeclared identifier SOURCE_PATH

Comment: Did you change the command-line argument to `/DSOURCE_PATH=C:\some\path\MyProg.exe`?

Comment: Actually, I now see that you are using `srcpath`/`SOURCEPATH`/`SOURCE_PATH` inconsistently. For `GetFileVersion`, you use it as a full path to file name, while in `Source:` you use is a a path to folder only (and you concatenate it with filename `MyApplication1.exe`) --- it all looks like you are actually not passing `SOURCEPATH` on command-line at all (or incorrectly) - and it's actually not possible at all (as explained in my answer). And you actually use the `SourcePath` predefined variable (what is a path to a folder) -- There are way to many issues in your script :(

Comment: It's the Compil32.exe compiler that's complaining about the variable SOURCE_PATH.

Comment: Isn't your question about `iscc.exe`?

Comment: Does the use of arguments mean you can't use Compil32.exe?

Comment: No it doesn't. But let first solve your question with `iscc.exe`, before we get to other problems...

Comment: Maybe I understand now --- What do you actually define on command-line? `srcpath` or `SOURCEPATH`? Doesn't you actually define `srcpath` and `#define srcpath SOURCEPATH` was your attempt to default to `SOURCEPATH` predefined variable when `srcpath` is not defined on the command-line?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on ["Inno Setup Preprocessor: Command Line Compiler Execution"](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=builtinsiss) I could define a command line parameter called `"MyCustomParam"` by using `/D` option like this:

```
.\ISCC.exe /DMyCustomParam=MyParamValue "MySetupScript.iss"
```

and then I wrote my setup script like the following, which gets the value which was defined for the parameter on the command line:

```
[Setup]
AppName={#MyCustomParam}
```